# Visual Studio cannot compile C++ project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, ie-plugins

The project is an IE plugin, which compiles on some computers, but not mine.

On my computer, Visual Studio 2015 Professional, I get this error when rebuilding the project:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TRK0002 Failed to execute command: ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT @C:\Users\td\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpa3439d68e5a945d29fbebe677944beda.rsp". The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.  IE.Plugin   C:\IE.Plugin\TRACKER    1
```

Windows Event Viewer shows this log message:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        SideBySide
Date:          7/19/2016 9:56:55 PM
Event ID:      59
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      ...
Description:
Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe".Error in manifest or policy file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe.Config" on line 0. Invalid Xml syntax.
```

Please help.

Comment: Please post the contents of the `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe.Config"` file on your computer. It should be a short text file in `XML` format.

Comment: It's corrupted. All raw bytes that can't be displayed as text.

Answer (score 1):

It is the file `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe.Config"` that got corrupted somehow.

Deleting the file lets Visual Studio build my project without any errors.